# improve XSLT 3.0 performance to avoid expensive preceding selection

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I have a input structure like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MessageFormat name='WagonStatus_Fplv' version='2.02'>
    <StructFormat name='K0-HEADER' delimOptional='n'>
        <FieldFormat name='SATZKOPF-K0' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='2' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        <FieldFormat name='Externer_Partner' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='35' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        <FieldFormat name='INTERCHANGEREFERENZNUMMER' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='14' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        <FieldFormat name='NACHRICHTENREFERENZNUMMER' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='14' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        <FieldFormat name='NACHRICHTENTYP' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='6' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        <FieldFormat name='TESTKENNZEICHEN' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        <FieldFormat name='VERSIONSNUMMER' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='2' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        <FieldFormat name='EDI-REFERENZNUMMER' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='14' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        <StructFormat name='SATZENDE' delim='\n' delimOptional='n'>
        </StructFormat>
    </StructFormat>
    <StructFormat name='FV-ISR-SST-GROUP' delimOptional='n' repeat='150'>
        <StructFormat name='F10-IDENTIFICATION-DATA' delimOptional='y'>
            <FieldFormat name='F000-IDEN' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='2' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F010-TYPE' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='6' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F020-TIME' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='14' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        </StructFormat>
        <StructFormat name='F20-PRODUCTION-DATA' delimOptional='y'>
            <FieldFormat name='F030-WAGO' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='12' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F040-FLAG' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F050-TRAI' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='17' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F060-CREA' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='8' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F070-WADA' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='12' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F080-FORA' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F090-FSCO' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='5' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F100-FSDE' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='24' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F110-INSR' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F120-INSC' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='5' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F130-INSD' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='24' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F140-FRON' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='3' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F150-DERA' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F160-DSTC' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='5' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F170-DSTD' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='24' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F180-REAL' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='12' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F190-TWEW' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='7' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        </StructFormat>
        <StructFormat name='F30-COMMERCIAL-DATA' delimOptional='y'>
            <StructFormat name='F31-GOODS' delimOptional='y' repeat='4'>
                <StructFormat name='F311-CONTAINER' delimOptional='y' repeat='4'>
                    <FieldFormat name='F240-SHGC' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='6' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                    <FieldFormat name='F250-WEGC' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='7' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                </StructFormat>
                <FieldFormat name='F220-SFGC' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='6' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                <FieldFormat name='F230-NUGC' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            </StructFormat>
            <StructFormat name='F32-GOODS-DESC' delimOptional='y' repeat='4'>
                <FieldFormat name='F260-WESH' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='7' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                <FieldFormat name='F270-RIDC' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                <FieldFormat name='F280-RIDG' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                <FieldFormat name='F290-HAIG' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                <FieldFormat name='F300-SUID' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                <FieldFormat name='F310-DALA' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='15' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            </StructFormat>
            <FieldFormat name='F200-TYTR' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F210-NUGO' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        </StructFormat>
        <StructFormat name='F40-CONTROL-LABEL-DATA' delimOptional='y'>
            <FieldFormat name='F320-FORA' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F330-FOST' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='5' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F340-FOSN' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='5' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F350-FOSD' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='24' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F360-FODA' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='8' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F370-CRCO' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='6' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F380-CRDE' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='24' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F390-CECO' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='6' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F400-CEDE' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='24' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F410-CONU' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='6' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        </StructFormat>
        <StructFormat name='F50-ROUTE-DATA' delimOptional='y'>
            <StructFormat name='F51-ROUTE-CODE' delimOptional='y' repeat='6'>
                <FieldFormat name='F430-TRRY' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                <FieldFormat name='F440-FRON' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='2' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                <FieldFormat name='F450-ORDE' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            </StructFormat>
            <FieldFormat name='F420-RONU' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        </StructFormat>
        <StructFormat name='F60-BROKEN-WAGON-DATA' delimOptional='y'>
            <FieldFormat name='F460-DADE' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='25' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F470-STDA' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='5' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F480-SDDA' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='24' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F490-DADA' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='12' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F500-DATY' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        </StructFormat>
        <StructFormat name='F70-CONS-NOTE-DATA' delimOptional='y'>
            <StructFormat name='F71-CARRIER' delimOptional='y' repeat='20'>
                <FieldFormat name='F710-CACO' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                <FieldFormat name='F720-CAST' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                <FieldFormat name='F730-CAPO' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='2' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                <FieldFormat name='F740-CAAC' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            </StructFormat>
            <StructFormat name='F72-COM-DEST-STAT' delimOptional='y'>
                <FieldFormat name='F750-DSCC' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='2' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                <FieldFormat name='F760-DSSC' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='5' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
                <FieldFormat name='F770-DSDE' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='24' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            </StructFormat>
            <FieldFormat name='F780-SWLT' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F790-CONT' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        </StructFormat>
        <StructFormat name='F80-LAST-EVENT-DATA' delimOptional='y'>
            <FieldFormat name='F810-LEDD' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F820-LETY' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='2' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F830-LEDT' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='12' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F840-LECC' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='2' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F850-LESC' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='5' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F860-LEDE' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='24' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F870-LETR' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='6' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        </StructFormat>
        <StructFormat name='F90-TRAIN-SITUATION-DATA' delimOptional='y'>
            <FieldFormat name='F910-TRST' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F920-MPIM' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F930-MPCC' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='2' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F940-MPSC' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='5' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F950-MPSD' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='24' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
            <FieldFormat name='F960-DTIM' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='6' strlenInChars='y' codepage='UTF-8'/>
        </StructFormat>
        <StructFormat name='SATZENDE' delim='\n' delimOptional='n'>
        </StructFormat>
    </StructFormat>
</MessageFormat>
```

The target structure should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <WagonStatus_Fplv>
    <K0-HEADER>
        <SATZKOPF-K0 length="2" start="1"/>
        <Externer_Partner length="35" start="3"/>
        <INTERCHANGEREFERENZNUMMER length="14" start="38"/>
        <NACHRICHTENREFERENZNUMMER length="14" start="52"/>
        <NACHRICHTENTYP length="6" start="56">
        <TESTKENNZEICHEN length="1" start="72"/>
        <VERSIONSNUMMER length="2" start="73"/>
        <EDI-REFERENZNUMMER length="14" start="75"/>
        <SATZENDE/>
    </K0-HEADER>
    <FV-ISR-SST-GROUP>
        <F10-IDENTIFICATION-DATA>
            <F000-IDEN length="2" start="89"/>
            <F010-TYPE length="6" start="91"/>
            <F020-TIME length="14" start="97"/>
    ...
</WagonStatus_Fplv>
```

So every FieldFormat in source document will be mapped as an elment node with length as attribute, and the start attribute is the sum of length of the preceding element nodes. And `<StructFormat name='FV-ISR-SST-GROUP' delimOptional='n' repeat='150'>` means this structure will be repeated with 150 times.

Until now with kindly help of `@Martin Hennen` I have this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:csb="http://www.dbcargo.org/csb" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0">
        <xsl:param name="msg" as="xs:string">H0 EVU_DBSRD PVG     Z24 ABF-RF  IR    ExternalPartnerID_uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu0202017-03-16-07.27.40.864320NJNJ   M1           80281261300008                        M2 16.03.201707:27:00Z1 H62430  16.03.2017                    16.03.201707:00:00+0027R1 00131800820664780201703154023641201703151159043706346965                                   000    JJ                                                R1 02031800819657480201703154045545201703151159306557346965                                   000    NN                                                </xsl:param>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:mode name="unroll" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="StructFormat[@repeat]" mode="unroll">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$this/@repeat != '*' ">
                <xsl:for-each select="1 to @repeat">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$this/@delimOptional = 'n' and $this/TagField and contains($msg, $this/TagField)">
                            <xsl:copy select="$this">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @repeat, node()" mode="#current"/>
                            </xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:copy select="$this">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @repeat, node()" mode="#current"/>
                            </xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="repeat" select="count(tokenize($msg, $this/TagField/@value)) - 1"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="1 to $repeat">
                    <xsl:copy select="$this">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @repeat, node()" mode="#current"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="StructFormat[not(@repeat)]" mode="unroll">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$this/TagField and not(contains($msg, $this/TagField/@value)) ">
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy select="$this">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @repeat, node()" mode="#current"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="FieldFormat[@repeat]" mode="unroll">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to @repeat">
            <xsl:copy select="$this">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @repeat, node()" mode="#current"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="complete-struct">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="unroll"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="{/MessageFormat/@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$complete-struct/*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="StructFormat">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="FieldFormat">

        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
        <!--    <xsl:attribute name="start" select="sum(preceding::FieldFormat/@length) /> -->
            <xsl:attribute name="length" select="./@length"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is, when I try to calculte the sum of preceding elements, the statement 
(`<xsl:attribute name="start" select="sum(preceding::FieldFormat/@length) />`) 
is just too expensive, so that XSLT engine (Saxon 9.8 HE) is not responding. Do I reach the limit of XSLT power here and have to use another technology like Java to accomplish this kind of task, or is there a way to avoid this expensive preceding selection to get an improvement of XSLT performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try whether an accumulator improves performance:

```
<xsl:accumulator name="preceding-length" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule phase="end" match="FieldFormat" select="$value + xs:integer(@length)"/>
</xsl:accumulator>

<xsl:template match="FieldFormat">

    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
        <xsl:attribute name="start" select="accumulator-before('preceding-length') + 1"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="length" select="@length"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion!! It does resolve my problem. with `xsl:accumulator` it is much much faster.

Is there a book to recommend, which summerizes the new key features added in XSLT 3.0 or man has to read through the specification to get them?

Comment: @dingjun - You can find a summary here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#whats-new-in-xslt3

Comment: Here examples of xsl:accumulators in XSLT spec.

https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#accumulators

Comment: I think Daniel has posted link with a good summary directly from the spec. I am not aware currently of a book dedicated to XSLT 3. There is a new book on XML in general published this year in German that at least also covers XSLT 3, see https://www.mitp.de/IT-WEB/Programmierung/XML.html, its author also has a web site covering lots of stuff at http://www.wilfried-grupe.de/Basics_XSL2.html. In the end you can get lost in any site covering all functions in XPath 3 https://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/ or all XSLT instructions http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/xsl-elements/, take your time.

Comment: When I put 
`<xsl:accumulator name="preceding-length" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule phase="end" match="FieldFormat" select="$value + xs:integer(@length)"/>
</xsl:accumulator>`

in my template, it works as expected, but how does the accumulator know, it should apply to the tree kept in the   
`<xsl:variable name="complete-struct">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="unroll"/>
    </xsl:variable>
`

, not apply to the source document tree?

Comment: There are rules on when an accumulator is applied, they are stated in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#applicability-of-accumulators, as for your variable, the section states "all accumulators are applicable to a temporary tree created using xsl:variable". As for the initial source document, the section says "For a document containing nodes supplied in the initial match selection, the accumulators that are applicable are those determined by the xsl:mode declaration of the initial mode. This means that in the absence of an xsl:mode declaration, no accumulators are applicable".

Comment: Is there a way to let my template `<xsl:template match="StructFormat[@repeat]" mode="unroll">` apply to a temporary docuemnt instead of initial source document . I tried following and it didn't work:
``` 
    <xsl:template match="/" mode="unroll" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('a.xml')/*"/>
        </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="unroll">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```
Thanks.

Comment: Please ask a new question where we can read all code snippets as well-formatted code samples in the question's text.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this is to use memo functions. The `f:totalLength()` of a `FieldFormat` is `(f:totalLength(preceding::FieldFormat[1]) + @length)`, so if you compute this in a memo function (`xsl:function cache='yes'`) the calculation will only involve one step back rather than scanning all the way back to the start of the file.

Another solution is to precompute the accumulated-lengths of every FieldFormat element in a forwards pass through the document, storing the result perhaps in a map from generate-id of the element to the total value. This could be done with something like

```
<xsl:map>
  <xsl:iterate select="//FieldFormat">
    <xsl:param name="total" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="new-total" select="$total + @length"/>
    <xsl:map-entry key="generate-id()" select="$total"/>
    <xsl:next-iteration>
      <xsl:with-param name="total" select="$new-total"/>
    </xsl:next-iteration>
  </xsl:iterate>
</xsl:map>
```

You could also use `fn:fold-left()` as an alternative to `xsl:iterate` (though not in Saxon-HE).

I guess this is also the way you would do it in earlier versions of XSLT, except you would hold the data in an XML structure rather than a map, and you would use a recursive template rather than using `xsl:iterate`.

Comment: Many thanks to well known Michael Kay. From your replies I can always learn something new :)

Comment: In the `<xsl:map-entry key="{generate-id()}" select="$total"/>` we don't need `{}` for `generate-id()`, right?

Comment: Yes, I remembered wrong, it's an expression not an AVT. Will edit.